# No audio after running Lennart Poettering's multitasking script

Tags: sound

For some odd reason, after running [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/11/alternative-to-200-lines-kernel-patch.html) and restarting I lost audio on my Linux partition (but not on my Windows one).

With the [volume controller appearing at max](http://yfrog.com/jkscreenshotdbp), why would I have no audio?

Comment: Did you use the patched kernel method mentioned toward the bottom of the page, or did you follow the main instructions for making it work on Ubuntu?

Comment: @Dennis VanMeter: I did the main instructions, as my title question clearly states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of reasons things could have "gone south."  For now, please see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/AlsaInfo and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio/Log.